# when we make a change to form bean in struts why we need to restart tomcat?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

When we make a change to form bean in Struts why we need to restart tomcat
and not when we make a change in an action class?

Comment: because form bean loads and initialize in JVM once. so when you make changes to that it will not get affected because old instance still loaded into JVM

Comment: And you can change that behavior.

Answer (score 4):

By default when you restart the tomcat then and then only the class loader runs again and the changes effects.

You can change that behavior by [configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) of [`reloadable`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute.

```
reloadable=true
```

> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected.